# Showing real values on UART-PC software

Tags: pic, serial, software

If we use a controller and wanted to send data via **UART** to **PC**. I trust serial data will be displayed on the software and is there any way you can display real values on the software apart from collecting the bytes and makes appropriate data type in PC software.

I am using PIC and I needed to send data via UART. And I ended up reading this question:

[Sending integers via PIC's USART](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42744/sending-integers-via-pics-usart)

Is there any software where we can send the data serially and the values will be displayed according to the data type?

How do we fix such problems? Can you suggest free software to monitor serial data and can be later used to view real values also.

Comment: Please capitalize the first word of your titles.

Comment: You are going to have to indicate to the PC first that the next few bytes sent over are of type `Int`. An integer is just a series of bits, as is a float and a double. `0x41` - What do you see there? I see decimal 65 of type `uint8_t`. Then again, it could be of type `char` and represent the letter 'A'. Or it might be an instruction to the CPU to load a register. The interpretation is completely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can send any data type you like. The trick is to send the type along with the value so that it can be decoded on the other side. Send a byte value containing the type first (e.g. `0x00` is `unsigned char`, `0x01` is `signed char`, `0x02` is `unsigned short`, etc.) and then follow it with the actual value data.

```
0x00 0x12 0x1c 0x1f 0x85 0xeb 0x51 0xb8 0x1e 0x09 0x40
    |
    V
18, 3.14
```

Comment: so float and other data type will be having similar code Byte (like  '0x00') right?. Is there any free software that shows real values on Pc after receiving serial data.I just needed to see Adc values (10 bit) on any free software and  monitor the changes.

Comment: You don't need free software for this. Most programming languages can convert the data trivially.
`>>> struct.unpack('<d', '\x1f\x85\xeb\x51\xb8\x1e\x09\x40')`
`(3.14,)`

Comment: Does 3.14 needs this much bytes for representation?. Or did i misread your suggestion.I trust this is part of GUI programming! .Thanks

Comment: A [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) [double-precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) value is represented in 8 bytes.

Comment: It also depends up on the compiler we are using right?I found c18 compiler takes 2 bytes for integer and 4 for float.That's why i had a confusion

Comment: `float` is a single-precision floating point type.